# How can I find out allowed quantum transitions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, laser

My active element is fluorine(F), I have an energy level diagram:

[image]

So, i must choose the pump's channel and find out what quantum transitions are allowed. How can i do it?